# How do I get sharedpreferences in Asynctask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I am writing an android application for my school project but i am stuck here. The problem is i have to access a `SharedPreferences` value and need it in an `AsyncTask` class. When I try to access it, it wont let me because of the context. How can i reach my `SharedPreferences` in my `AsyncTask`?

```
public class CheckAccess extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, Boolean>{


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {

        //Trying to get sharedpreferences here wont work.

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I mean access values in it.

Comment: I think you can not access a `sharedPreference` from an `AsynTask`, at least in `doInBackGround`. Have you tried to access it from `onPreExecute`?

Comment: Just pass the value you need into the AsyncTask, possibly in a constructor. You could even pass in a context, but I wouldn't access that in `doInBackground()` as it may not be threat safe.

Comment: I tried:  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); but it give me the error: The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (CheckAccess)

Comment: You can do it easily. See [tlahoda's answer for a summary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23598080/383414) or [my answer for a more detailed explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28084320/383414).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Override `onPreExecute` or `onPostExecute` method of `AsyncTask` and get `SharedPreferences` there:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    //get sharedPreferences here
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(<SharedPreferencesName>, <Mode>);
}
```

Please note that `getSharedPreferences` is an `Activity` method. So, you need to call it through `Context` if you are not using it in `Activity`.

Comment: Good idea, but i am having trouble with getting it. How to continue this line in preExecute? SharedPreferences prefs = ...

Comment: I think the problem is that i don't call it through Context since i am not using it in an activity. How can i do it?

Comment: Simply pass the context to the `AsynTask` constructor.

Comment: Then you can not get the preferences I think. You need the Activity

Comment: You must be using the AsynTask class from an activity. Before calling it, call the constructor of class where Asynctask is residing. In the constructor, pass the context.

Comment: I am using it like this: jsonObject = new GetData().execute(cardId).get(); What changes do i need?

Comment: Define a constructor of `CheckAccess` to accept `Context`. In the constructor definition, initialize Context. Pass the `Context` while creating object.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is wrong. See [tlahoda's answer for a summary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23598080/383414) or [my answer for a more detailed explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28084320/383414).

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: Thanks for correcting me. I totally missed it. I have corrected my answer

Answer (score 4):

You can get SharedPreferences in a background thread using the PreferenceManager like this:

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(<YourActivity>.this);

Answer (score 3):

You can get `SharedPreferences` in the background using an `AsyncTask`.

The mistake is in this line, where you are passing in the wrong type of variable:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

In your case, the word `this` refers to the `AsyncTask` instance that you are calling if from.

---

What I do is I pass the `Context` in to the task in the `execute()` method. See the code below for a working example:

```
    new AsyncTask<Context, Void, String>()
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Context... params)
        {
            Context context = params[0];
            SharedPreferences prefs =
                    context.getSharedPreferences("name of shared preferences file",
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            String myBackgroundPreference = prefs.getString("preference name", "default value");

            return myBackgroundPreference;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            Log.d("mobiRic", "Preference received in background: " + result);
        };

    }.execute(this);
```

In the above example, `this` refers to the `Activity` or `Service` that I call this from.