# How to put method into the AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, methods, android-asynctask

Hello i have little problem. How and where i should put that method in asyncTask or maybe better, how it should look in asyncTask.

**Here's my code**

```
public void licz()
{
     wyniki.setText("");
        N = Integer.parseInt(liczbaN.getText().toString()); 
        tablica = new String [90];
        int i=0;
            for(licz1=99;licz1>=10;licz1--)
            {
                for(licz2=10;licz2<=licz1;licz2++)
                {
                    if(N==licz1/licz2 && licz1%licz2==0)
                    {
                        String nap1 = Integer.toString(licz1);
                        String nap2 = Integer.toString(licz2);
                        napis = (nap1+ " " + nap2 +"\n");   // moj string
                        lista.add(napis);
                        tablica[i]=napis;
                        i++;    
                        wyniki.setText("");
                    }                   
                }
                String listString = "";
                for (String s : tablica)
                {
                    listString += s;
                }
                listString=listString.replaceAll("null", "");
                wyniki.setText(listString);
            }   
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This code doesn't seem to warrant an AsyncTask.

Comment: Becouse values in loop and in array will be much higher

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596903/how-do-i-get-sharedpreferences-in-asynctask/23596935#23596935

Comment: there are more about sharedpreferences i want just to know how  implement that method to asynctask

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare the `AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>`.
2. Put this code inside `doInBackground()`.
3. Replace all occurences of `wyniki.setText(whatever);` with `publishProgress(whatever);`
4. In `onProgressUpdate()`, use `wyniki.setText(progress[0])`;

The last two steps are important, you cannot change UI views from the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that extends AsyncTask and override its doInBackground() method. Put your licz() method inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `AsyncTask` class and override its methods:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Put your code here

        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //do something after background execution is complete
        //Executes on main thread
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         //do something before background execution starts
        //Executes on main thread
    }
}
```

Call `new MyTask().execute("");`

**Note:**
Update UI related changes in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: But how it will work if i have all layout in other class. When i move only method it will crash so much

Comment: You can do it in `onPostExecute`. Make layout variables as class variable. Call `wyniki.setText("");` on `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0):

Change your method and make it return a String instead of void

```
public String licz() {
    String result = "";
    // do your fancy array stuff
    return result;
}
```

Then create a class extending `AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>` and in the `doInBackground()` call your method and return the result. Than use the result in the `onPostExecute()` and update the TextView:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override   
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return licz();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        wyniki.setText(result);
    }
}
```