# Get string from SharedPreferences in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to develop an app for sending emails, actually I just started studying java.

I created strings "email_address" and "pass" in my sharedpreferences so user can change them. Then I try to send email, using that data -->

```
  //Creating a new session
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                //Authenticating the password
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                    return new PasswordAuthentication(sharedPrefs.getString("email_address", "a"), sharedPrefs.getString("pass", "a")); }
            });

    try { <...>
```

And then I got this :

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Android Studio points me at this line -->

```
return new PasswordAuthentication(sharedPrefs.getString("email_address", "a"), sharedPrefs.getString("pass", "a")); }
```

If I hardcode my gmail and password in that line, it works perfectly, but I need an option to change these (in case of user can't build this app from my source code). Please help, I already spent 3 hours browsing this site and androiddevelopers too. :(

Comment: Did you initialize `sharedPrefs` by getting it from `context`?

Comment: Because you are learning Java, you have to know what is a null pointer and how to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: And as @AndiGeeky says, your `sharedPrefs` variable is not initialized. That is the problem.

Comment: I've got this public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

Comment: @adalPaRi I searched about this and it seems like it must be initialized in onCreate, but I don't have oncreate in this class.

Comment: @me_yy you can initialize just before your `//Creating a new session`, but you need to have also the context. So, to help you, can you post all your code? Your AsyncTask is in a single file or is a subclass?

Comment: @adalPaRi yes of course, http://pastebin.com/27v9040Y ( I just added onpreexecute method from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596903/how-do-i-get-sharedpreferences-in-asynctask but this don't works anyway.

Comment: @adalPaRi I just did this http://pastebin.com/u7i5YyX5 and it almost worked! But 'this' is marked red and it says : Error:(53, 112) error: incompatible types: SendMail cannot be converted to Context.    // What is this?? O_o How do I get that code to work..

Comment: @me_yy best follow my answer

Answer (score 0):

It really isn't recommended to hold any form of passwords in your `sharedPreferences`, if you're creating an application where you would like the user to choose where they want to send it from e.g. their own personal Gmail use `Intents` instead but if you are determined to send emails automatically, I would recommend setting up a Gmail `SMTP` email address to send it from and pass the username and password to your Authenticator through there. (Java mail API)

Email Intent Example: [Send Email Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent)

but if you would like to send an email automatically: [Example of sending email using Java Mail API](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api)

Answer (score 0):

Aswering from your comment in question:

First of all, this is doing nothing, due to variable is LOCAL inside the method:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    //get sharedPreferences here
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}
```

Then, one solution could be, initialize SharedPreferences when initialize AsyncTask with the constructor:

```
public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String sharedText1) {
    //Initializing variables
    Context context1 = context; // this line is doing nothing..
    this.email = email;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.sharedText1 = sharedText1;
    sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // add this line to initialize variable
}
```

And finally, you can acces to sharedPrefs variable without null pointer exception:

```
sharedPrefs.getString("email_address", "a")
```